# Using diff on multiple files with variable names

Tags: bash, file, terminal

I have a bunch of files, ex:

```
error1.sol
error2.sol
comment1.sol
```

and so on

My program has created these output files:

```
myerror1.sol
myerror2.sol
mycomment1.sol
```

and so on

How can I in an elegant manner use `diff` to match

```
diff error1.sol myerror1.sol
diff error2.sol myerror2.sol
```

automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for fname in my*.sol
do
    diff "${fname#my}" "$fname"
done
```

The above looks for every file created by your program (`my*.sol`).  Each such file is assigned, in turn, to the variable name `fname`.  Using `fname`, we can get the name of the source file by removing `my` from the front.  This is done with `${fname#my}`.  `diff` is then run on these two files.  The loop repeats for as many such files as there are in the current directory.

You may find the output easier to read if an `echo` command is added to show which files are being compared:

```
for fname in my*.sol
do
    echo Comparing "${fname#my}" and "$fname"
    diff "${fname#my}" "$fname"
done
```